# Can I group values only when multiple values exist within a time window?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm working with a poller that polls every minute, and I query aggregate data from it by the hour. The 1-minute data looks something like this

```
my_metric{system="sys1", subsystem="ss1", group="A"} 1
my_metric{system="sys1", subsystem="ss2", group="A"} 1
my_metric{system="sys1", subsystem="ss3", group="B"} 1

my_metric{system="sys2", subsystem="ss4", group="A"} 1
my_metric{system="sys2", subsystem="ss5", group="B"} 1
my_metric{system="sys2", subsystem="ss6", group="A"} 1
```

I want to count the number of systems each hour that are in each group. However, there are some systems that undergo a change from A to B within the 1-hour window, and using `count by (system, group)` or similar queries counts these systems twice. So is there a way to use label_replace or group or count distinct to do something like - if A and B both exist within the 1-hour window, then label_replace with "Updated"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to test the query its hard to guess whether they will work as intended, especially for these non-trivial queries.

The first operator we need is the `unless` operator. It works like an XOR

```
metricA unless metricB
```

returns metricA when `metricB` does not exist and `metricB` when `metricA` does not exist. In combination with `avg_over_time` we can do the following:

```
avg_over_time(my_metric{group="A"}[1h])
unless
avg_over_time(my_metric{group="B"}[1h])
```

gives us all the metrics that existed only in one group within the last hour.

Now we need to handle the cases where a system switched a group. In that case you need to decide if you want to have that counted for A or B. There we can use the `and` operator,

```
metricA and metricB
```

returns you the values of metric A where also metric B exists.

```
avg_over_time(my_metric{group="A"}[1h])
and
avg_over_time(my_metric{group="B"}[1h])
```

returns you a metric for group A, if they existed the same time. (If you need it the other way around, just switch A and B)

The next operator is `or`:

```
metricA or metricB
```

simply metricA as long it exists while it returns metricB when metric A does not exist.

```
(
   avg_over_time(my_metric{group="A"}[1h])
   unless
   avg_over_time(my_metric{group="B"}[1h])
)
or
(
   avg_over_time(my_metric{group="A"}[1h])
   and
   avg_over_time(my_metric{group="B"}[1h])
)
```

should return you now the metric when it existed only in one group, or the metric for group B if it existed only in both groups. The only thing you need to do is put a `count by (group)` around it and it should bring you the expected results.

(In general its a good practice to build up non-trivial queries step by step and test them each time, so you know what metrics are counted and if they are exactly what you are looking for)